How do I use Python ctypes to interface with Fortran parameterized derived types?
I am trying to write python code to interact with Fortran code that I have written that uses parameterized derived types, however my python code is resulting in segmentation faults.
A minimal reproduction of the python code I've been trying to write is as follows:
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path


class Derived(ctypes.Structure):
    ...

    
library = ctypes.CDLL(str(Path(__file__).parent / "test_lib.so"))

n = 4
c_n = ctypes.c_int(n)

Derived._fields_ = [
    ("n", ctypes.c_int),
    ("y", ctypes.c_double * n)
]

d = Derived()

library.test_derived(ctypes.byref(c_n), ctypes.byref(d))

print(d.y[:])

Where test_lib.so is a shared object library compiled from the following Fortran code:
module test_module
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int
    implicit none

    type, bind(c) :: Derived(n)
        integer(c_int), len :: n
        real(c_double), dimension(n) :: y
    end type Derived

contains


    subroutine test_derived(number, der) bind(c, name="test_derived")
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: number
        type(Derived(n=number)), intent(out) :: der

        der%y = 2.d0
        write(*, *) "Fortran:", der%n, der%y
    end subroutine test_derived


end module test_module


program main
    use test_module
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: n_points_1 = 5
    integer, parameter :: n_points_2 = 6
    type(Derived(n=n_points_1)) :: d1
    type(Derived(n=n_points_2)) :: d2

    call test_derived(n_points_1, d1)
    call test_derived(n_points_2, d2)

end program

I'm expecting the output of the Fortran write statement and the python print statement when I run the python script, but I get Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV) instead, with no other output. When I compile the Fortran code as an executable and run it, it works as expected. I have written similar Python code to interface with normal Fortran derived types, using ctypes.Structure, but this approach seems to fail with parameterized derived types. Is there something I'm missing?

Does your compiler not complain about the completely illegal type, bind(c) :: Derived(n)?

Might not be the only one, but check [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions).

@francescalus I'm compiling with gfortran, with -wall -wextra -wsurprising, and get no warnings and a functioning executable. This syntax seems perfectly in keeping with the syntax of a derived type at https://fortran-lang.org type [,attribute-list] :: name [(parameterized-declaration-list)]

That syntax rule does not fully describe restrictions given by Fortran. It must also follow the constraint: "A derived type with the BIND attribute shall not have type parameters". A parameterized type is not C interoperable.
